# How to fix corrupted opencl.dll in Windows 10, if SFC and DISM are failing?

Tags: windows-10, dism

*It took me several hours to fix the issue because the local component store was corrupted and the computers are accessing a local WSUS server instead of the public update server by Microsoft (and because I use Dism very rarely). For reference and to help other people with the same issue, I will write down a problem description and provide a solution.*

Since upgrading to Windows 10 Pro Version 1511 (Build 10586) I have a problem with a corrupted filed *opencl.dll* in several locations.

I tried `sfc.exe /scannow`, but it failed to fix the issue. The error messages are, among others:

```
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3a Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-r..xwddmdriver-wow64-c_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_3dae054b56911c22\opencl.dll do not match actual file [l:10]"opencl.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 g2VAunZ6/2J1G3oL7kf9fjInPUA9VYeiJcl9VKgizaY=} Expected: {l:32 9rnAnuwzPjMQA7sW63oNAVhckspIngsqJXKYSUeQ5Do=}
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:10]"opencl.dll" of microsoft-windows-RemoteFX-clientVM-RemoteFXWDDMDriver-WOW64-C, version 10.0.10586.0, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:125]"Microsoft-Windows-RemoteFX-VM-Setup-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0.RemoteFX clientVM and UMTS files and regkeys"
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3d Hashes for file member \??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\opencl.dll do not match actual file [l:10]"opencl.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 g2VAunZ6/2J1G3oL7kf9fjInPUA9VYeiJcl9VKgizaY=} Expected: {l:32 9rnAnuwzPjMQA7sW63oNAVhckspIngsqJXKYSUeQ5Do=}
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3e Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-r..xwddmdriver-wow64-c_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_3dae054b56911c22\opencl.dll do not match actual file [l:10]"opencl.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 g2VAunZ6/2J1G3oL7kf9fjInPUA9VYeiJcl9VKgizaY=} Expected: {l:32 9rnAnuwzPjMQA7sW63oNAVhckspIngsqJXKYSUeQ5Do=}
2015-12-08 08:50:43, Info                  CSI    00003c3f [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [l:23 ml:24]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64"\[l:10]"opencl.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

Okay, so the issue is clear now. Unfortunately, *SFC* is unable to resolve the corruption because the local component store also got corrupted. Unfortunately, I lost the error messages indicating the component store corruptions.

So I tried `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to no avail. It fails with error **0x800f081f**, indicating another problem with the source files.

```
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    Exec: Download qualification evaluation, business scenario: Manual Corruption Repair
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    Exec: Clients specified using Windows Update.
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    WU: Update service is not default AU service, skip. URL: https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/, Name: Microsoft Update
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    WU: Update service is not default AU service, skip. URL: https://fe2.ws.microsoft.com/v6/, Name: Windows Store
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    WU: Update service is not default AU service, skip. URL: https://fe3.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/, Name: Windows Store (DCat Prod)
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    WU: WSUS service is the default, URL: (null), Name: Windows Server Update Service
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    DWLD:Search is done, set download progress to 20 percent.
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    Nothing to download, unexpected
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to collect payload and there is nothing to repair. [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
2015-12-08 08:57:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to repair store. [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
```

Looking at the error messages, it becomes clear that Windows is set to use our local WSUS server and therefore Dism is unable to retrieve the valid file from the repositories. While I am sure that I could somehow configure WSUS to provide the necessary files, I don't know how and I need a quick fix. *(If someone knows how to configure WSUS accordingly, please provide information).*

Limiting access to the local storage by adding the paramter `/LimitAccess` would be useless as the local component store is also corrupted, as mentioned earlier.

I experienced this issue on two machines. A *refresh* of Windows 10 did not fix the issue.

Comment: fwiw there's a long thread here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/sfc-scannow-report-opencldll-bad/4209b042-1b7b-4fa2-a720-2c0e489d137b about problems with this dll.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To fix this problem, you need to have the ISO of the exact build you have installed.

1. Mount the ISO image.
2. Create a temporary directory to mount the Windows Image File (WIM).
   `mkdir C:\WIM`
3. Mount the WIM file.
   `Dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:D:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\WIM /ReadOnly`
4. Run Dism with the following parameters.
   `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\WIM\Windows /LimitAccess`
5. When done, unmount the image and delete the folder
   `Dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\WIM /Discard
   rmdir C:\WIM`
6. It's mandatory to restart your computer, or SFC and DISM will still show errors.

That should fix the issue.

**Edit**
As pointed out in the comments, there might be a more direct approach. The TL;DR is, that it did not work for me, hence my more detailed approach. But I am interested if you had any problems with the direct approach. Please comment.

Comment: you can point to the WIM without needing to mount the WIM: http://superuser.com/a/870956/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your comment. I read about that and I tried it to no avail. It always failed with an error, that was 0x800f081f I remember right. It was surprising to see that I could not find anything regarding the `/source:wim` parameter in the official documentation for the [Dism Command Line Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825099.aspx).

Comment: I read it here in the content to enable features: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2013/03/29/features-on-demand-part-2.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I tried it several times and I am 100% certain that it does not work. Maybe they removed the option in Windows 10, or it is bugged. Or maybe there is an (unlikely) difference in the option between appending it to /RestoreHealth and /Enable-Feature. That is also the reason why it took me so long to figure this out. And why I wrote about it in serverfault.com. Still, thanks for pointing it out. Maybe we get some more responses over time. I found many people with issues but no solutions in the interwebz who may just stumble over this.

Comment: ok. I've bookmarked it and will tell users your way if the direct WIM way fails.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what we discussed. Thanks again :)

Comment: this also helped for other users: http://www.borncity.com/blog/2015/12/09/windows-10-dism-reparatur-bemngelt-quelle-fehler-0x800f081f/comment-page-1/#comment-27331 strange that mounting works, but directly passing the WIM not.

Comment: This method does not appear to work with the initial installation medium used to upgrade from Windows 7 or 8.1. Step (3) will throw the 0x800f081f error even when the installation media is converted from ESD using NTLite and then mounted using Dism. I suspect there is something wrong with this particular version of the installation image.

Comment: After downloading the Windows 10 image using the Media Creation Tool, here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10
the resulting img had an install.esd in it that had to be converted to a WIM in order to be mounted by Dism. I used NTLite to do so. After that, Daniel's instructions worked fine. Just note that the /index parameter in the third step should probably reflect the version of Windows, Pro or Home, that you're restoring (in other words, use /index:1 for Pro and /index:2 for Home)

Comment: I had tried other methods to fix my opencl.dll corrupt issue. Including trying to access a WIM file directly.  Mounting it, and then using the mounted image as the source, as you show in your answer, finally worked.  After rebooting, sfc was then able to fix that file.  Thank you.

Comment: I too had to mount directly, using /source:wim:X:\sources\install.wim gave error 87, path not found. (And yes, triple checked that path was valid.)

Comment: Wanted to add as well - opencl.dll corrupt issue as well, only your steps (mounting and all) got Dism to use the provided image.
Thanks again.

Comment: Worked for me. +1 for this answer, -1 for Microsoft. This shouldn't be so hard.

Comment: @EliB. - Anyone wanting to use the esd should be able to use the form `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:repairSource\Install.esd`  note the missing "limitaccess".

Answer (score 10):

From various forums on the Internet, I've assembled following repair procedure:

1. Download MediaCreationTool from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209
2. Download Windows 10 Pro ISO with `MediaCreationTool.exe` to `c:\temp\windows.iso`
3. Use 7-zip for extract file `c:\temp\windows.iso` to folder `c:\temp\windows`
4. Convert `install.esd` to `install.wim`

   > `Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:c:\temp\windows\sources\install.esd /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:c:\temp\windows\sources\install.wim /compress:max`
5. Check index and windows version in `.wim` file
   `-`index is used for next Dism command in parameter `/Source:wim:path_to_wim:[index]`

   > `Dism /Get-WimInfo /wimFile:c:\temp\windows\sources\install.wim`
6. Restore health windows components from downloaded and converted windows image (wim):

   > `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:c:\temp\windows\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`
7. Repair corrupted files:

   > `sfc /scannow`

   It will repair corrupted files - success message: `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.`
8. Restart Windows
9. Check System files again to be sure for succesfull repair:

   > `sfc /scannow`

   Success message after scan: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: Thanks this finally fixed my Windows 10 install which I just did a clean install not long ago. Seems to get screwed up and sfc fails soon after even doing a clean install! Anyways will see how long it stays fixed this time! Guess Microsoft still hasn't fixed it in latest win 10 update since seems to be known problem for 1511 build http://news.softpedia.com/news/microsoft-acknowledges-system-file-checker-issue-in-windows-10-version-1511-502258.shtml p.s. didn't have to do step 4 though since install.wim was already there when I extracted the windows ISO.

Comment: Thank you for response. System file checker will be corrupted after installing graphic dirvers. But now is enough to repair system only with run SFC /SCANNOW - It seems now is available right version of opencl.dll in winsxs folder. PS: It's true, step 4 may be ommited, if you download bootable ISO, but media creation tool download only the ESD file (version designed for upgrade Windows 10). Media Creation Tool is best choice for automatic download correct installation media :-)

Comment: Step 4 (extracting the WIM file) did it for me. Excellent guide. Thanks.

Comment: step 6 fails for me with "the source files cannot be found", error 0x800f091f

Comment: I googled for error 0x800f091f and problem may be with installation .NET Framework 3.5. If you have only version 4+, then try install version 3.5 too. Try MS installation guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Error 0x800f091f may be problem with Group Policy. Run gpedit.msc and in folder "Computer Configuration/Administratitive Templates/System" find item "Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair". I have set Not Configured or Disabled. Check that the .wim file is not corrupted (dism /CheckIntegrity). Check c:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log for error detail. Check your windows version (ver.exe) against install.wim version (Dism /Get-WimInfo /wimFile:c:\temp\windows\sources\install.wim /Index:1) - it's my tip for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

An ESD is not an "encrypted" WIM, it is a WIM that has been highly packed/reencoded very differently (with a more complex structure).

A WIM is just "fast" compressed by unbreakable units of 4KB or 16KB, using a fast Huffmann compression. An ESD uses more advanced LZ-based compression without block size limitations. This compresssion does not allow the image to be open in read-write-mode as the compression is global (each file in the archive is no longer compressed separately, multiple logical files can share the actual storage of segments, to reach a mush higher compression level, notably when there are many small files with common headers parts, such as collections of icons, or parts of their digital signature data, copyright notices, HTML headers, embedded scripts and so on).

An SWM is a multipart WIM that has been split in multiple files with smaller sizes with a (rough) maximum size, but it is still writable, and can be stored on multiple DVDs.

CBS providers allow several archiving formats that can be supported by DISM, including WIM, CAB, ZIP, VHD, VHDX, multisession ISOs... But Windows comes with two builtin providers for the WIM and ESD formats (ESD is new to Windows 10, with Windows 8, only the WIM format was supported, but the images were larger)

The ESD format has been tuned for allowing the full multilingual distribution of Windows 10 to fit on a single DVD with less than 3GB...

You can transform an ESD to WIM, but the result will be a much larger file. The inverse conversion is also possible (so that you can read-write in the expanded WIM) to pack it again into a new ESD. Decompressing an ESD to WIM is relatively fast, but compressing a WIM to ESD requires lot of CPU ressources and is much longer (that's why you can't read-write directly into an ESD but you can do that quite easily in a WIM with modest CPU usage).

When you "mount" an ESD with DISM, the first thing it will do is to expand the ESD into a temporary storage and act on it as if it was a WIM, so that you can update files in this local storage. Unmounting it will require two steps: recreating a WIM (quite fast), and then pack it again into an ESD (very slow).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with opengl.dll as follows:

1. Mount the Windows 10 image.
2. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:F:\sources\install.esd\1\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-r..xwddmdriver-wow64-c_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_3dae054b56911c22\
3. sfc /scannow

Good luck!

Comment: ESD ISO is not restored Windows Image. You must use ONLY WIM ISO, that you can download from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few days going down these paths and finally found a solution for my situation.  I'm running Windows 10 version 1511 Build 10586.545.  Here is my progression:

1. This started for me with a Windows Update failure (error 0x800705b4).
2. I then chased this error doing Windows Update troubleshooters, WUResets, disabling antivirus, etc..  [This Link](https://www.thegeneralistit.com/blog/2015/10/02/fixing-windows-10-update-error-0x800705b4/) is a good article giving options for that issue (although they didn't help me)
3. I then went down the DISM and SFC path.  This ServerFault post was very helpful in that attempt.  Unfortunately none of these options helped.  I kept getting told I have a corrupt opencl.dll file, and running all sorts of variations of DISM /RestoreHealth didn't work.  I kept getting 0x800f081f (Source files could not be found)
4. I next tried to manually copy opencl.dll from a clean ISO into C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  This never worked, even after messing with taking ownership, etc.  I finally disabled the NVIDIA GeForce GPU driver in Device Manager (Leaving an Intel driver still enabling display), and was able to copy the clean opencl.dll into C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

From here, Windows Update started working again.

So in summary, if you're struggling with these errors and nothing seems to work, try disabling the NVIDIA GeForce drivers and then trying some of these steps (or manually copying in a clean version of the DLL).

Answer (score 1):

Due to not having a local copy and for a separate reason unable to download the ISO file (the ISO was not of the Windows 10 type I have installed) There is a [hotfix solution here](http://appuals.com/repair-corrupt-opencl-dll-in-windows-10/) which I used which involves downloading a specialist file called "SFCFix":

> SFCFix is a brilliant little utility that is capable of fixing this problem for you by repairing/replacing the corrupt dll file.
>
> Once the executable file for SFCFix has been downloaded, move it to your Desktop.
>
> A [ZIP file containing everything SFCFix needs](https://www.sysnative.com/forums/attachments/windows-update/18034d1450113095-guide-opencl-dll-corruption-sfc-dism-windows-10-update-1511-th2-sfcfix-zip) in order to repair/replace your corrupt opencl.dll file. You will be asked by the website to register on it to gain access to the ZIP file, you should do so as it is completely free.
>
> Once sfcfix.zip has been downloaded, move it to your Desktop. Close all open programs. Drag the ZIP file onto the executable file for the SFCFix program and then release it.
>
> SFCFix will launch and start applying the fix for the corrupt dll file. Let it work its magic.
>
> Once SFCFix is done, it will create a file named `SFCFix.txt` on your Desktop. Open this file and, if SFCFix was successful at repairing/replacing your corrupt opencl.dll file,

Please note that running the SFCFix.exe file *without* the hotfix ZIP will be a long slow process that achieves very little, you need to run it with the ZIP file drag/drop method, and the result is almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize an esd image, per the DISM technet article.  An ESD (Electronic Software Delivery) image is simply an encrypted version of a WIM, and also happens to utilize a far better compression algorithm than the WIM format does (generally around 1.5x better compression).

If all one has is an ESD, but would rather use a WIM, you can convert an ESD to WIM with the DISM export command.  You can also convert a WIM to ESD by specifying /compress:recovery within export or capture command.  Converting one to the other is resource intensive, and because of this, it's recommended to utilize the ESD to WIM script that was written years ago and is available on the MSFN forum. Utilizing the script, only ~50% of system resources are dedicated to the export versus the 90%+ that is generally utilized for the export.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to another Windows 10 Pro x64 machine and copied the opencl.dll file (from the same directory).  Then I took ownership of the bad opencl.dll, renamed it to opencl.old, and copied in the new one.  Reboot back into safe mode and run sfc /scannow and it comes back good.   In my case, this was the ONLY bad file listed in cbs.log ... I can see where it might be better to have sfc work if you have many corrupt files and don't want to patch each individually.  But if your problem is just the one dll, then a simple copy seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the install image (`install.esd`) from the Creator's Update installation media is incompatible with the DISM method described here. You will get error `0x800f081f` no matter which kind of command you type. It also does not help to extract the correct `install.wim` out of the ESD file. 
Finally, I even tried mounting the WIM file to no avail as well.

See also discussions at https://www.sysnative.com/forums/windows-10-a/22564-dism-error-0x800f081f.html#post179723

Update: The persisting error has nothing to do with the dism command or the wim files. It is due to a package named Microsoft-Windows-TestRoot-and-FlightSigning-Package for which no working sources are available. The files are in C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages and have to be moved away from there. Also, there are two references in the registry which have to be deleted.  See the linked sysnative thread for details.