# Cannot uninstall KB4338815

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, update, windows-update

Trying to uninstall this update as it breaks one of our .net applications but it will not remove. Tried in Installed Updates which fails, also tried removing via DISM which fails with the log below (I had to remove timestamps and a little inconsequential data to make it all fit character limits)

```
PID=18444 TID=24308 Scratch directory set to 'C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\'. - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir
PID=18444 TID=24308 DismCore.dll version: 6.3.9600.17031 - CDISMManager::FinalConstruct
PID=18444 TID=24308 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Windows\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Getting Provider DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Getting Provider DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Manager: PID=18444 TID=24308 Successfully created the local image session and provider store. - CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Getting Provider DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM.EXE: 
DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
DISM.EXE: 
DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=6.3.9600, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=32
DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 6.3.9600.17031
DISM.EXE: Executing command line: "C:\Windows\system32\Dism.exe" /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~9600.19069.1.9 /quiet /norestart
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Getting Provider FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Loading Provider from location C:\Windows\System32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Windows\System32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
DISM Manager: PID=18444 TID=24308 physical location path: C:\ - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
DISM Manager: PID=18444 TID=24308 Copying DISM from "C:\Windows\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation
DISM Manager: PID=18444 TID=24308 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9" - CDISMManager::LoadRemoteImageSession
DISM Image Session: PID=12568 TID=23152 Instantiating the Provider Store. - CDISMImageSession::get_ProviderStore
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Initializing a provider store for the IMAGE session type. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\OSProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\OSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
DISM OS Provider: PID=12568 TID=23152 Defaulting SystemPath to C:\ - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
DISM OS Provider: PID=12568 TID=23152 Defaulting Windows folder to C:\Windows - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
DISM OS Provider: PID=12568 TID=23152 Host OS verion is 6.3 - CDISMOSServiceManager::SetDllSearchPath
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Attempting to initialize the logger from the Image Session. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\LogProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\LogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\PEProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, Warning  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Getting Provider DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23152 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Manager: PID=18444 TID=24308 Image session successfully loaded from the temporary location: C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9 - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Getting Provider OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Target image information: OS Version=6.3.9600.18384, Image architecture=amd64
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Getting the collection of providers from an image provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\CbsProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\CbsProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finished initializing the CbsConUI Handler. - CCbsConUIHandler::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 CBS is being initialized for online use. More information about CBS actions can be located at: %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log - CDISMPackageManager::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::RefreshInstanceAndLock
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\MsiProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\MsiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\IntlProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\IntlProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\IBSProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, Warning  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\IBSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\DmiProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\DmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 Successfully loaded the hive. - CDISMOSServiceManager::DetermineBootDrive
, InfoDISM   DISM Driver Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Further logs for driver related operations can be found in the target operating system at %WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.offline.log - CDriverManager::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\UnattendProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\UnattendProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\Wow64provider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, Warning  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed to get the IDismObject Interface - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider(hr:0x80004002)
, Warning  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\Wow64provider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004002)
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\SmiProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\SmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\EmbeddedProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, Warning  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\AppxProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\AppxProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\AssocProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\AssocProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\GenericProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\GenericProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\TransmogProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\User~1.UK1\AppData\Local\Temp\A1A37FBE-A48D-4C56-9AD4-60240829E6E9\TransmogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 Current image session is [ONLINE] - CTransmogManager::GetMode
, InfoDISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 Audit Mode: [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 GetProductType: ProductType = [ServerNT] - CTransmogManager::GetProductType
, InfoDISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 Product Type: [ServerNT] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=12568 TID=23384 Product Type ServerNT : [Yes] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Got the collection of providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Log Provider
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OSServices
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Package Manager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Package Manager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: MsiManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: MsiManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IntlManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: IntlManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DriverManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DriverManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Unattend Manager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Unattend Manager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SmiManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AppxManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AppxManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AssocManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AssocManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: GenericManager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: GenericManager.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: Edition Manager
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Edition Manager.
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Getting Provider DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Processing the top level command token(remove-package). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Encountered the option "packagename" with value "Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~9600.19069.1.9" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Package Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~9600.19069.1.9 with CBS state 7(CbsInstallStateInstalled) being mapped to dism state 5(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED) - CDISMPackage::LogInstallStateMapping
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Initiating Changes on Package with values: 5, 0 - CDISMPackage::Internal_ChangePackageState
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 CBS session options=0x100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23152  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0831) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
, Error    DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0831)
, Error    DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed processing package changes - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChanges(hr:0x800f0831)
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::RefreshInstanceAndLock
, Error    DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Failed while processing command remove-package. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0831)
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
, Error    DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F0831
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12568 TID=23384 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: 
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
, InfoDISM   DISM.EXE: 
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
, InfoDISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=18444 TID=24308 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Also tried this I found elsewhere

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop appidsvc
net stop cryptsvc
```

3. Rename the software distribution folders backup copies. To do this, at a command prompt, type the following commands. Make sure that you press Enter after you type each command.

   Ren %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak

   Ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
4. Restart the BITS service, the Windows Update service, and the Cryptographic service. To do this, at a command prompt, type the following commands. Make sure that you press Enter after you type each command.

   net start bits

   net start wuauserv

   net start appidsvc

   net start cryptsvc

Comment: found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345418/windows-10-update-kb4345418 in this thread: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2167349-cannot-uninstall-update-kb4338815-from-server-2012r2 with some actions you don't mention. Hope its helpfull

Comment: Your immediate problem appears to be component store corruption, which can sometimes be fixed with, e.g., [SFC](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-sfc-scannow-to-repair-windows-system-files-2626161).  But KB4338815 is from July, so unless you're *way* behind on updates, it has been superceded several times over anyway.  Winding back to June isn't a very sensible option, you'll probably be better off fixing the problem in your application.

Comment: Not possible to fix the application as the KB in question breaks .net apps, it was a documented issue and affects many applications. 8815 was installed in August, am able to uninstall it from other servers just fine.

Comment: Hmmm.  All of the known issues listed in the [KB4338815 article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4338815/windows-81-update-kb4338815) should have been fixed when you installed [the August update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4343898).  Can you provide more information about the specific issue you're having?

Comment: ... however, if uninstalling KB4338815 resolved the problem on your other servers (even though it should have had absolutely no effect) then we have to assume it will also fix it on this one.  Perhaps someone has time to post an answer about fixing component store corruption, but in the meantime a Google search should give you lots of things to try, e.g., [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de1c33ee-fbe4-40a2-891b-b0932b31efea/component-store-corruption?forum=winserver8gen).

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/q/741487/94065 but if the existing answers don't work for you, you might wish to edit your question to include details, e.g., the error messages from SFC and DISM.  (I should mention that the last time I ran into component store corruption I eventually had to resort to manually copying the damaged files from another machine using robocopy, so SFC and DISM definitely not a cure-all.)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Update Standalone Installer handles removing updates.

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:4338815
```

Once you reset the software distribution folder you can no longer uninstall updates. You can try replacing the .BAK files and running the uninstall. Otherwise you'll need to restore from backup.

Comment: deleteting the `c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder will prevent the uninstall of alread installed patches?

Comment: Tried wusa prior to backing up/removing software distribution folder, it also failed - "installer encountered an error 0x800f0831"

Comment: Deleting the software distribution folder shouldn't have any effect on your ability to uninstall updates.